# Remove href link after form reset

Tags: javascript, html, href, onchange

I have the following mock form and I'd like the `link` to either disappear, or reset to the default selection.

**HTML :**

```
<form name="formName" target="_blank">

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:600px;">

  <div style="float:left;"><span>Pick AAA</span><br>
    <select id="AAA" onchange="showLink()">
      <option value="11">Eleven</option>
      <option value="12">Twelve</option>
      <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
      <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;"><span>Pick BBB</span><br>
    <select id="BBB" onchange="showLink()">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>  
  </div>

  <a href="generateLink()" id="link" target="_blank"></a><br><br>

  <div style="float:left; margin-left:120px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top:70px;">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to"><br><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Selection">
  </div>
```

**JS :**

```
function generateLink()
{
  var A = document.getElementById('AAA').value;
  var B = document.getElementById('BBB').value;

  if(B == "1" || B == "2")
    link ='http://' + B + '.' + A + '.domain';
  else if(B == "3" || B == "4")
      link ='http://' + B + '.' + A + '.domain/link.jsp';
  else
    link ='/404.html';

  return link;
}

function showLink()
{
  var link = generateLink();

  document.getElementById("link").href = link;
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = link;
}

document.formName.onsubmit = function(){
    this.action = generateLink();
}
```

[What happens now](https://jsfiddle.net/6pthwesg/) is that when I hit **Reset Selection**, the `select` elements are being reset but the link itself doesn't disappear due to the `onchange` command. Does anyone know how I can reset the link as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, [`Reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method restores a form element's default values. This method does the same thing as clicking the form's reset button.

#### Why Link is not reset to default?

Link is Anchor Tag which is not part of form Field. Form Reset Feature is to reset Form Fields not other elements like `anchor, p, h1-h6`.

#### Take a look at the working code.

```js
function generateLink() {
  var A = document.getElementById('AAA').value;
  var B = document.getElementById('BBB').value;

  if (B == "1" || B == "2")
    link = 'http://' + B + '.' + A + '.domain';
  else if (B == "3" || B == "4")
    link = 'http://' + B + '.' + A + '.domain/link.jsp';
  else
    link = '/404.html';

  return link;
}

function showLink() {
  var link = generateLink();

  document.getElementById("link").href = link;
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = link;
}

document.formName.onsubmit = function() {
  this.action = generateLink();
}

document.formName.onreset = function(){
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = ''
}
```

```html
<form name="formName" target="_blank">

  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:600px;">
    <div style="float:left;"><span>Pick AAA</span><br>
      <select id="AAA" onchange="showLink()">
      <option value="11">Eleven</option>
      <option value="12">Twelve</option>
      <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
      <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;"><span>Pick BBB</span><br>
      <select id="BBB" onchange="showLink()">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <a href="generateLink()" id="link" target="_blank"></a><br><br>

    <div style="float:left; margin-left:120px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top:70px;">
      <input type="submit" value="Go to"><br><br>
      <input type="reset" value="Reset Selection">
    </div>

</form>
```

> #### Other Improvments, if your code is not test code.

1. Avoid Inline Styles and keep it as [styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style).
2. Use Form Field [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Examples).
3. Instead of span tags. Avoid `<br>` element and manage with CSS Styles.
4. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer and the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
document.formName.onreset = function(){
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ended up choosing Venkatraman's answer because of the first part and his final suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the link programmatically , so you need to remove it programmatically, too:

```
document.formName.onreset = function(){
    let linkEl = document.getElementById("link");
    linkElement.href = '';
    linkElement.innerHTML= '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ended up choosing Venkatraman's answer because of the first part and his final suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

reset() method only resets the data. You need to hide the link yourself.